# Mongo rep sets and how to remove a dead node seconday with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a dead node on ec2.  How do I use pymongo to remove the dead secondary from the rep set?

```
{u'date': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 16, 11, 53, 53),
 u'members': [{u'_id': 0,
               u'health': 1.0,
               u'name': u'xxxxxxxxx:27017',
               u'optime': Timestamp(1352810702, 1),
               u'optimeDate': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 13, 12, 45, 2),
               u'self': True,
               u'state': 1,
               u'stateStr': u'PRIMARY',
               u'uptime': 507560},
              {u'_id': 1,
               u'health': 1.0,
               u'lastHeartbeat': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 16, 11, 53, 51),
               u'name': u'ffffffffff:27017',
               u'optime': Timestamp(1352810702, 1),
               u'optimeDate': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 13, 12, 45, 2),
               u'pingMs': 1,
               u'state': 2,
               u'stateStr': u'SECONDARY',
               u'uptime': 163187},
              {u'_id': 2,
               u'errmsg': u'socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for jjjjjjjj:27017',
               u'health': 0.0,
               u'lastHeartbeat': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 16, 11, 53, 14),
               u'name': u'jjjjjjjjjj:27017',
               u'optime': Timestamp(1352810702, 1),
               u'optimeDate': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 13, 12, 45, 2),
               u'pingMs': 0,
               u'state': 8,
               u'stateStr': u'(not reachable/healthy)',
               u'uptime': 0}],
 u'myState': 1,
 u'ok': 1.0,
 u'set': u'heythat'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the replica set configuration from the `local.system.replset` collection:

```
>>> from pymongo import Connection
>>> c = Connection()
>>> conf = c['local']['system.replset'].find_one()
```

If you check in a mongo shell what the rs.reconfig wrapper does, you see that it also increases the version and then runs a special `replSetReconfig` command.

```
default:PRIMARY> rs.reconfig
function (cfg, options) {
    cfg.version = rs.conf().version + 1;
    cmd = {replSetReconfig:cfg};
    for (var i in options) {
        cmd[i] = options[i];
    }
    return this._runCmd(cmd);
}
```

Just do the same from Python. Modify the `conf['members']` document (e.g. remove the dead node) and update the version (add 1). Then run the `replSetReconfig` command against the admin database with the updated `conf` dictionary as parameter.

```
>>> # change conf['members'] accordingly
>>> conf['version'] += 1
>>> c['admin'].command({'replSetReconfig':conf})
```